# If user types open parenthesis in textarea, how to add closing paren automatically?

Tags: vue.js

I have a `textarea` element in my template. I want Vue to add closing paren `)` when user types open paren `(`, just like any programming text editor does.
How can I achieve this with Vue?

First thing I tried was `v-on:keydown` event. I checked what information is available in `KeyboardEvent` in callback method. Unfortunately I can't even see a position of a typed character so I can't modify a model variable bound to textarea. I do not know the position of user's cursor when he presses the character key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is my solution to the problem. It will add paired char if required and will keep the cursor between characters

```js
const SINGLE_QUOTE = "'";
const LPAREN = "(";
const RPAREN = ")";
const LBRACK = "[";
const RBRACK = "]";

const CHARS_REQUIRE_PAIR = {
    [SINGLE_QUOTE]: SINGLE_QUOTE,
    [LPAREN]: RPAREN,
    [LBRACK]: RBRACK
};


new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        title: 'The VueJS instance'
    },

    methods: {
        smartTyper(evt) {
            let keyTyped = evt.key;
            let inputElement = evt.target;
            if (!Object.keys(CHARS_REQUIRE_PAIR).includes(keyTyped)) {
                return
            }
            let caretPosition = inputElement.selectionStart;
            let closingChar = CHARS_REQUIRE_PAIR[keyTyped];

            inputElement.value =
                inputElement.value.substr(0, caretPosition) +
                closingChar +
                inputElement.value.substr(caretPosition);
            inputElement.setSelectionRange(caretPosition, caretPosition);
        }
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <textarea v-on:keydown="smartTyper"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Eddited:**

What do you think about this? https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/242422/

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <textarea v-model="inputText" @keypress="changeInput"></textarea>
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
changeInput (event) {
  if (event.key === '(') {
    // Remember coursor position
    var cursorStart = event.target.selectionStart
    var cursorEnd = event.target.selectionEnd
    event.preventDefault()
    // Prevent adding additional (
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.inputText = this.inputText.substr(0, cursorStart) + '()' + this.inputText.substr(cursorStart)
    })

    setTimeout(() => {
      // Maybe you can find better solution for this
      // Without this part coursor will go to the end of text area
      event.target.setSelectionRange(cursorStart + 2, cursorEnd + 2)
    }, 4)
  }
}
```

Comment: I got your idea, but this one is too primitive. What if I type open paren in the middle of already existing string? Another problem I faced with similar attempts is that caret jumps to the end , while my goal is to make it stay between parens :(

Comment: @Derp I have spent some time to improve this one for you, hope that it helps. It was a bit challenging for me to implement this.

Comment: you can prevent reactive form update caused by model change if you edit `event.srcElement.value` directly, no need for timeout

Comment: I think that I have solved your issue, and regarding event.srcElement.value I have tried it and when you type in ( in the middle of string cursor jumps to the end.